# to find duplicate file name in the adls gen 2 location using pyspark databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, pyspark

I am trying to find that whether there is a same name file already existing in the adls gen 2 location i.e
i need to check in the adls gen2 location if same name files are already existing
for example

```
abc.csv
def.csv
xyz.csv
abc.csv
```

since we could see that abc.csv is exists 2 times so it need to through an exception or a message that duplicate files are existing

Comment: You can't have 2 files with the same name in a given folder in adls gen2. Make your question very specific.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, you cannot have a duplicate file name in the ADLS Gen2 location.

**Reason:** ADLS Gen2 doesn't allow to create a file with the same name which already exists.

[image]

If you want to check if a file exists on a filesystem, please refer to the below code:

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeFileClient

account_name = 'ADLS_Name'
account_key = 'ADLS_Access_Key'
file_system_name='FileSystem_Name'
file_client = DataLakeFileClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
        "https",
        account_name
    ),
    file_system_name=file_system_name,
    file_path='test.txt',
    credential=account_key 
)

try:
     file_client.get_file_properties()
except Exception as error:
    print(error)    
    if type(error).__name__ =='ResourceNotFoundError':
        print("the path does not exist")
```